# Sparkle - sign_update via ssh: "Unable to access required key in the Keychain"?

Tags: macos, keychain, sparkle

- Sparkle-1.21.0
- OS X 10.11

`generate_appcast` doesn't work with `.dmg` file:

> Error generating appcast from directory
>   /Users/quanta/Downloads/updates  Error Domain=SUSparkleErrorDomain
>   Code=1001 "No usable archives found in
>   /Users/quanta/Downloads/updates" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No
>   usable archives found in /Users/quanta/Downloads/updates}

So, I have to create `appcast.xml` manually:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<rss xmlns:sparkle="http://www.andymatuschak.org/xml-namespaces/sparkle" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>x</title>
        <item>
            <title>1.0.0.2891</title>
            <pubDate>Thu, 06 Dec 2018 17:25:26 +0800</pubDate>
            <sparkle:minimumSystemVersion>10.7</sparkle:minimumSystemVersion>
            <enclosure url="https://example.com/x.dmg" sparkle:version="1.0.0.2891" sparkle:shortVersionString="1.0.0.2891" length="86454539" type="application/octet-stream"/>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Got this error when testing:

> DSA signature validation of the package failed. The update contains an installer package, and valid DSA signatures are mandatory for all installer packages. The update will be rejected. Sign the installer with a valid DSA key or use an .app bundle update instead.

First time running `sign_update`, I choose "Always allow", so it does not ask for password in the next time:

```
$./bin/sign_update /path/to/x.dmg
sparkle:edSignature="x==" length="105562628"
```

But I still got this error when running via ssh:

```
$ ~/Downloads/Sparkle-1.21.0/bin/sign_update /path/to/x.dmg
ERROR! Unable to access required key in the Keychain -25308 (you can look it up at osstatus.com)
```

I know that we can use `openssl` to do the same thing: https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle/blob/master/bin/old_dsa_scripts/sign_update

but how can I export `dsa_priv.pem` from my keychain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is `login.keychain` is locked when running via ssh.

We have to unlock it before running `sign_update`. Put the following command into a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

security unlock-keychain -p "$pa55w0rd" $HOME/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```